# Can username or password have a hash # in it according to w3c spec?

Tags: url, passwords, standards, w3c

When crafting a url using basic authentication:

```
https://username:password@someurl.com/some/api/path
```

is it valid or invalid if either the `username` or `password` contains a `#` hash sign? Hash's are typically found on the end of URLs, so I'm not sure if it's a valid character to use in the username and/or password.

I can't tell from the w3c url spec... It says that `username` and `password` should be `alphanum2`, which I can't figure out what that means exactly.

http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

We are encouraged more often these days to carefully pick more complicated passwords, including special characters like `#` hashes.

Answer (score 3):

(**Warning**: Note that [RFC 7230 disallows](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#appendix-A.2) to use the `userinfo` subcomponent in HTTP/HTTPS URIs; and for all URIs in general the format `username:password` is [deprecated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1).)

The HTTPS URI scheme is [defined in RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-2.7.2), which references RFC 3986 for the definition of the [`authority` component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2).

The `authority` component can contain a [`userinfo` subcomponent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1), and its syntax is defined to be:

> ```
> userinfo    = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" )
> ```

In the [appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) you can lookup how these parts are defined. To summarize, these are the characters that are allowed:

- `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`
- `0`-`9`
- `-`
  `.`
  `_`
  `~`
  `!`
  `$`
  `&`
  `'`
  `(`
  `)`
  `*`
  `+`
  `,`
  `;`
  `=`
  `:`
- any [percent-encoded character](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)

So you may not use the `#` directly in the `userinfo` subcomponent, but you can use it in its percent-encoded form (`%23`), e.g. for `foo#bar`:

```
https://foo%23bar@example.com/some/api/path
```

Answer (score 1):

It's defined a few lines further down:

```
alphanum2              alpha | digit | - | _ | . | +
```

So, the answer is clearly **no**.

#### In Addition:

> We are encouraged more often these days to carefully pick more complicated passwords, including special characters like # hashes.

Yes and of course you can use them for HTTP Basic Auth, but then you cannot log in via URL